# Clearing a single cookie with a set value for ALL users on a domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

So I finally got this fantastic cookie script working for my site www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?69591-Looking-for-a-quot-do-not-show-this-page-again-quot-checkbox-script :

```
// Skip this Page Script (c)2012 John Davenport Scheuer
        // as first seen in http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/
        // username: jscheuer1 - This Notice Must Remain for Legal Use
        ;(function(setting){
            var cook = {
                set: function(n, v, d){ // cook.set takes (name, value, optional_persist_days) - defaults to session if no days specified
                    if(d){var dt = new Date(); 
                        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + d);
                    d = '; expires=' + dt.toGMTString();}
                    document.cookie = n + '=' + escape(v) + (d || '') + '; path=/';
                },
                get: function(n){ // cook.get takes (name)
                    var c = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\x20*' + n + '=([^;]*)');
                    return c? unescape(c[2]) : null;
                }
            };
            if(cook.get('skipthispage')){
                //Hide element when cookie exists
            }
            else {
                //Show element when cookie does not exist
            }
            if(!document.cookie){cook.set('temp', 1);}
            if(document.cookie){
                jQuery(function($){
                    $('#optout').css({display: ''}).append(setting.optoutHTML).find('input').click(function(){
                        this.checked? cook.set('skipthispage', '1', setting.days) : cook.set('skipthispage', '', -1);
                        this.checked && setting.gowhenchecked && location.replace(setting.page);
                    });
                });
            }
        })({
            days: 1, // days cookie will persist
            page: '',
            gowhenchecked: true, // true/false - should page switch when the box is checked?
            optoutHTML: '<label for="optoutcheckbox">Don\'t show this again: <input type="checkbox" id="optoutcheckbox" value=""></label>'
        });
```

However;
I am using this to hide a splash page that pops up when people initially visit my site, and it gives them the option to hide this splash page using a 1day long cookie.

This splash page contains information about the site I'm working on, and it's ever changing. So I need a quick and efficient way of clearing all cookies whenever the information changes.

So what I need is a button that I can click in my ACP, that clears these cookies and once again displays the splash page for people visiting my site.

I've been trying to get this to work using a lot of different methods, but none seem to work.

Thanks to jscheuer1 for this lovely script.

Regards,
Fredric T

---

EDIT:
I should add: the ACP is located in a subdirectory from where the script is.

http://example.com/index.php // This is where the script is loaded

http://example.com/admin/index.php // This is where I need the button to be.

If the above is not possible, I guess I can use PHP to only allow display if the session user is set as an admin. But I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by generating a 64 byte string in my database, to replace the old value whenever changes are made, which I want people to be able to see.

Bound that to a string and inserted it into the Javascript.